# CSS - Spacing shows up when switching to different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS issue, actually a spacing that shows when being under a different screen size. Please have a look at the picture below to understand better.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:70%"></div>

<div class="subTitle">Subtitle is here</div>

    <div class="details">
  <ion-grid class="borderBottom" no-padding>
    <ion-row padding>
         </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <button ion-button full color="light"></button>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .subTitle{
 padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
font-size: 4.7vw;
background-color: #22a800;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-weight: 600;
 }


 .details{
 width: 100%;
bottom:0;
background: white;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-top:1px solid #dedede;
 width:100%;
 position: fixed;
background: #f9f9f9;
  }
```

**Normal**

[image]

**When switched to another screen size, the issue appears:**

[image]

I am doubting that the issue is on the following line:

```
   <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:70%"></div>
```

Where the height is set to 70%, as the green bar on some other screen sizes goes below "**SOME INFO IN THIS BOX**"

Comment: Please inspect the element (space) in chrome and take a screenshot of the dev tools CSS etc

Comment: The question is... you say that thing is 70% height... but 70% of what? The body does not know it's own height...

Comment: Start with something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/uozufwrx/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is... it's still 70%, but your original 70% was set based on the first screen - and it was just a 'magic number' that worked... but as you've found - doesn't work when the screen is any larger or smaller.

You may need to use some flex-box here - or some JavaScript to check the browser height and then make some decisions based on the element sizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/xws3e18z/

```
<div class="map">
  map
</div>

<div class="sub-title">
  sub-title
</div>

<div class="other-stuff">
  other-stuff
</div>

<div class="button">
  button
</div>
```

...

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.map {
  background: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sub-title {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.other-stuff {
  background: white;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.button {
  background: lightgray;
}
```